# How to make a closing accordion when you click outside of it?

Tags: jquery, click, accordion

Please help me!
I create a simple accordion and I'm trying to make it close when you click anywhere on the page, except for accordions content.

See JSFiddle: `jsfiddle.net/2DaR6/201/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check to see if the clicked element was in the accordian or not

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$( "#acc" ).is(e.target) && !$( "#acc" ).has(e.target).length) {
        $('#acc').accordion('activate', -1);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2DaR6/202/

Comment: but what if you want this script to exclude what the other extraneous div?